# Auto reply not working during quiet hours

Tags: cortana, quiet-hours

I have enabled the option to send an auto reply text message for contacts not allowed to break through during quiet hours but none of my callers are getting the auto reply messages. How do I fix this?

Comment: By "callers" I assume you mean only people making a phone call? What about people who text you? Do they get it?

Comment: Yes that's right i mean callers as people making a phone call but  even the people who  text me also do not get an auto reply

Answer (score 1):

You also have to make sure cortana is allowed to run in the back ground (battery saver settings) for quiet hours to work